# Issue adding component to IContainer

Tags: c#, .net

I have an IContainer called container and I'm trying to add a component to it using the add method. When adding it I get this error

> Error 1   The best overloaded method match for
>   'System.ComponentModel.IContainer.Add(System.ComponentModel.IComponent,
>   string)' has some invalid
>   arguments C:\Users\Dan\Source\Workspaces\Bio-Catalysts
>   repack\Biocats_Repack\itas.s200.biocats.business\SOP\SOPOrderLineVwItems.cs   19  13  itas.s200.biocats.business

Heres the code:

```
namespace itas.S200.Biocats.Business.SOP
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using Sage.Common.Data;
    using Sage.ObjectStore;


    public class SOPOrderLineVwItems : PersistentSOPOrderLineVwItems
    {

        public SOPOrderLineVwItems()
        {
        }

        public SOPOrderLineVwItems(System.ComponentModel.IContainer container)
        {
            container.Add(this, null);
        }

        //public SOPOrderLineVwItems(System.Data.IDataReader reader) : 
        //        base(reader) 
        //{
        //}

        [System.ComponentModel.DesignerSerializationVisibility(System.ComponentModel.DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)]
        public new virtual SOPOrderLineVwItem this[int index]
        {
            get
            {
                return ((SOPOrderLineVwItem)(base[index]));
            }
            set
            {
                base[index] = value;
            }
        }

        [System.ComponentModel.DesignerSerializationVisibility(System.ComponentModel.DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)]
        public override Sage.ObjectStore.PersistentObject Owner
        {
            get
            {
                if ((this.Query.Owner == null))
                {
                    this.Query.Owner = new SOPOrderLineVwItem();
                }
                return this.Query.Owner;
            }
        }

        [System.ComponentModel.DesignerSerializationVisibility(System.ComponentModel.DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)]
        public new virtual SOPOrderLineVwItem First
        {
            get
            {
                return ((SOPOrderLineVwItem)(base.First));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Can provide more code/info if required

Thanks

Comment: Does `PersistentSOPOrderLineVwItems` inherit from `System.ComponentModel.IComponent`?

Answer (score 0):

```
public class SOPOrderLineVwItems : PersistentSOPOrderLineVwItems, IComponent
```

> IComponent Add() takes a IComponent as argument.
>   [Add](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yda71ax(v=vs.110).aspx)

and since you do this

```
container.Add(this, null);
```

you need `this` which is `SOPOrderLineVwItems` to be an `IComponent`